# How to replace phrase in php?

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

I tried replace phrase in php by function str_replace. it's only replace two word. Ex: `str_replace("noi that","noi thiet",$subject)`.

I want replace phrase > 2 word. Ex: str_replace("noi that Mien Nam","noi that Mien Bac", $subject). But it not true. Can you help me? Thanks you

Comment: Show $subject value

Comment: why to replace the first three words with the same value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are not assigning converted string to again to string variable

```
<?php
$subject = "noi that Mien Nam now my test";
$subject = str_replace("noi that Mien Nam","noi that Mien Bac", $subject);
echo $subject ;
?>
```

check this : https://eval.in/608524 its working

If you want to replace multiple words with another words

use this code

```
<?php
$subject = "noi that Mien Nam now my test";
$src = array("noi that", "Mien Nam");
$dst   = array("noi teit", "Mien Bac");
echo $newsubject = str_replace($src, $dst, $subject);
?>
```

Check this : https://eval.in/608527

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
<?php
$subject = "my name is xyz abc i leave in jaipur";
$str =  str_replace("my name is xyz","hello dear what are", $subject); 
echo $str;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question i think you want to replace more than one string from a given String. Below is the solution

```
$search  = array('programming', 'a PHP');
$replace = array('own', 'My');
$subject = 'This is a PHP programming language';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
//Output:
//This is My own language
```